# IE and border-radius

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

For those of you who need this to work and have tried meta bla bla bla and nothing seems to work and you just want to jump out the window...

COMPADABILITY MODE.   Go to Tools -> Compadibility Mode and turn off all that crap.

Thanks for the help guys! (except the 3 F-tards who voted me down)

Comment: What version of IE? Only 9+ supports border-radius.

Comment: What other borders properties are you setting? What element are you applying this to? Please provide a complete test case so we can reproduce the problem. http://sscce.org/

Comment: Post your actually code then

Comment: If you need <IE9 support, you could mimic the `border-radius` effect by using a transparant image that looks like a rounded corner. Or just leave it like it is, since I doubt it's really worth the effort ;)

Comment: Your last edit makes this closer to a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) but you still need the styles that actually set border-style / colour / etc and the markup for the div.

Comment: true if all else fails squared is fine but everyone is always telling me NOT to be squared so I try my best.

Comment: Quentin - what?  are you saying <div class="title"> ?  already done.

Comment: @AlexKosmač — I can't see it in the question.

Comment: OK- So many things missing. One, youcould just use border-radius:10px. Second, where is the html you're applying the class to? man..

Comment: @AlexKosmač — You've edited in the div now. You're still missing any code to make the border visible in the first place.

Comment: I tried border-radius as well, did not work.  tried the meta crap with individual references to each corner...nope.  I'm not posting the entire file on here it's about 1180 lines of code which is not relative to this question.  I feel like if you need that, then you most likely can't help me but I do appreciate your effort.

Comment: you have no content in your div to make a border with? there is no background color/image, what are you trying to actually have a border radius of? This is incomplete.

Comment: @AlexKosmač — I don't want all 1180 lines. I want the minimum amount of code to actually replicate the problem. I refer you, once again, to http://sscce.org/

Comment: Hmm well I just typed up a test page and it works haha....I copied and pasted the code from the original page.  So I'm thinking there is something on there messing with it.  The width and height props are being applied, background image, just not the rounded corners.  Do you know of anything that would prevent that?

Comment: Ok I posted the actual code.  It works in the test code I wrote but not the actual code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internet Explorer (under version 9) does not natively support rounded corners.

There's an amazing script for your problem: http://css3pie.com/

Comment: Did you read my question at all?  Already tried that.  (I do havea doctype for HTML5 at the top)

Comment: The OP mentioned in the comments that they are using IE 11, not 8.

Comment: Sorry my comment was when you said use the meta tag =P  I do know you caught yourself!

Comment: no problem, initial i missed that. for me works fine with this meta tag and IE 11

Comment: Yea I got it working on a test page but the one I need it to work on...it of course doesn't.  =(

Comment: Why downvote? Use css3 where avalaible and pie for all the other legacy / crappy ies..

Comment: @GiacomoPaita — The question isn't about IE 8, so this answer isn't relevant to the problem.